# Games keep crashing on newly built PC

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, crash, gpu, gaming

I recently built a new PC for a friend. The components are:

- Ryzen 7 2700X
- RTX 2070 Super Windforce OC
- 16 Gb 3200 MHz Vengeance PRO RGB RAM
- Gigabyte B450 Aorus Elite
- 750 Watt Corsair Power Supply

I did a basic GPU Overclock (+110 MHz core clock, +700 MHz memory clock).

MSI Kombustor ran fine for 20 minutes, so I thought everything is fine. When I started a game, it crashed instantly.

I thought if it was possible that the graphics Card overheated, but temperatures seems to be fine. (max GPU: 75°C, CPU: 66°C).

I removed the overclock and the games still crashed. After I let the system cool for about half an hour, I was able to play for a few minutes, until the games crashed again.

I also don't know why the games crashed, because they just say was a problem. When I click on the button to show crash logs for example in Minecraft, nothing happens. It seems like there is no log at all. The OS crashed into a BSOD once, but never again after that. That's basically all the information I managed to gather.

Do you have any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: You will have to provide us more information than just indicating the system crashes.  There are far to many possible causes for this behavior.

Comment: The OS itself doesn't crash. The games crash. Sometimes i managed to get into game lobbies and even start a game, but most of the time it just crashed when starting. I also don't know why the games crashed, because they just say was a problem. When I click on the button to show crash logs for example in Minecraft, nothing happens. It seems like there is no log at all. The OS crashed into a BSOD once, but never again after that. That's basically all the information I managed to gather

Comment: If it is the games crashing that makes it even more difficult to figure out, and also the likelihood there are multiple different issues.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible issues, but without any more specifics I would start by checking the following:

- Temperatures: You said you checked max CPU and GPU temperatures, that is good. Make sure you are checking while there is an active load - when the load is suspended, the CPU and GPU will both cool very, very rapidly (many degrees in less than a second). Also, if there are any other sensors available on the motherboard (some have many, some have few) try to get a read on those. Make sure all fans are spinning! If you built this PC, did you install the heat sink on the CPU correctly? It's also not unheard of for a motherboard to come from the factory with a heatsink poorly installed on a secondary chip (no paste, warped surfaces making poor contact, etc). Those can be checked, but I'd save that for a last resort.
- Voltages: If you are fiddling with settings to over clock, if you have adjusted any voltages you might have accidentally set one too low, which can cause crashes. DO NOT increase voltages without knowing what you are doing, you can easily cook your new rig!
- Drivers / Hardware incompatibilities: Make sure all drivers are correct and up to date. Search the web for other people using a same piece of hardware and having the same problem. For example, enter into a search engine your motherboard model number followed by "games crash". Sometimes there are also parts that work well alone, but don't work well in combination with a certain other part. [Here](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/gigabyte-b450-and-m-2-pcie-ssd-freezing-and-crashing.3415372/) is a link to someone with a similar motherboard describing repeated crashes after they installed an M.2 drive.
- Installed software: What else is installed? Could a malware/virus scanner, or a virus, or some other sort of software be causing problems?
- Look for common patterns: Is it all games? Are there any games that don't crash? What about a heavy workload that is not a game? You may be able to at least narrow the problem down to a *type* of workload (CPU, GPU, Disk, Network, etc)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you :D I will definitely check the temperatures under full load. I will also see if the cooler is mounted correctly, bit I've seen no problem with that so far. I didn't change anything about the voltages, because as you said, you shouldn't mess with that stuff unless you are experienced with it. The drivers should all be up to date. All the games I tried so far crashed. Sometimes quicker and sometimes it took a while. I first thought it was a problem with the GPU, but Kombustor and 3D Mark run fine without any issues. I tried cinebench for the CPU and it ran fine, too.